# Wordpress list pages return

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with listing pages in wordpress. I'm making template that requires tabular data in header like this

```
<td><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/index_04.gif" alt="" width="133" height="41" border="0"></a></td> 
<td><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/index_05.gif" alt="" width="122" height="41" border="0"></a></td> 
<td><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/index_06.gif" alt="" width="148" height="41" border="0"></a></td> 
<td><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/index_07.gif" alt="" width="137" height="41" border="0"></a></td>
```

wp_list_pages() and wp_page_menu both return pages like unordered list ul, but I need pages links to link them to their appropriate links.

Is there any way to return pages links only, or something I can make pages fit inside this tabular data. 
Template is already styled so I want to add this without changing these tabular appearance.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried:

```
<?php wp_page_menu('echo=0'); ?>
```

this will  return the list as an HTML text string to be used in PHP. take a look at the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu)

Comment: try print_r() the results, and see if it is an array.

Comment: it returns <ul> again, but never mind, I will try this code http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_list_pages-change-css?replies=9#post-1545306 looks like it should solve problem. Just I hope I will manage to link pages properly